# What are the advantages of using precision for NUMBER data format in ORACLE?

Tags: oracle, sqldatatypes

Should I use a precision for number data format? I know it ensures portability but what is other advantages of using precision? Does it have an effect on indexes?

Comment: I believe this kind of question is too broad for SO

Comment: The advantage is that you can store decimals if you need to.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, One of my friends said that it speed ups indexes. Is it true?

Comment: Apart from the fact that you can't "speed up an index" (you might speed up _accessing_ the index) this is irrelevant. You should declare the data type such that it can hold the data you want to store. If you need to store decimals you **have** to use a precision. If you don't then you shouldn't - it's also about documenting what you want to store in that column.

Comment: I think you're approaching this from the wrong angle. You should use the appropriate data type (including constraints, which is what the scale and provision provide) for the data you will store.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - not sure what you mean; an unconstrained `number` can hold decimals? (Or with default precision and scale if you prefer, but then in those terms you can't have a number without both).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Advantages are explained in details in the documentation:

 https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#i16209

> When you specify numeric fields, it is a good idea to specify the
>   precision and scale.
>   **This provides extra integrity checking on input.**

---

The precision and the scale of numbers have **no any impact** on indexes, a storage and the speed of queries.
The size of values in the column can have inpact on an index size and it's speed.
But hardly anyone knows, that Oracle stores numbers on the disk in **a varying width - not a fixed witdth format.**

It can be checked with the help of `vsize` function, which gives a size of a value on the disk in bytes:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions213.htm

Here is a simple experiment:

```
create table my_numbers(
  my_number number
);

insert into my_numbers values(1);
insert into my_numbers values(9);
insert into my_numbers values(99);
insert into my_numbers values(999);
insert into my_numbers values(9999);
insert into my_numbers values(99999);
insert into my_numbers values(999999);
commit;

select my_number, vsize( my_number)
from my_numbers;

MY_NUMBER                        VSIZE(MY_NUMBER)
---------- ---------------------------------------
         1                                       2
         9                                       2
        99                                       2
       999                                       3
      9999                                       3
     99999                                       4
    999999                                       4
```

And now:

```
UPDATE my_numbers set my_number = my_number + 1;
commit;
select my_number, vsize( my_number)
from my_numbers;
MY_NUMBER                        VSIZE(MY_NUMBER)
---------- ---------------------------------------
         2                                       2
        10                                       2
       100                                       2
      1000                                       2
     10000                                       2
    100000                                       2
   1000000                                       2
```

As you see, declared precision and scale have no any impact on a space occupied on the disk by numbers.